# What changes can make serialized class versions incompatible?

Tags: java, serialization, versioning

I'm experimenting with the java serialization API to create small persistent objects.  In my research I have found a lot on the importance of versioning, so you can detect and handle incompatible changes between the stored object model and the current object model.

What I can't seem to find is what changes to the object model can actually break compatibility.  Does removing a primitive member variable break it?  Does adding one?

What changes to a Serializable class will cause the readObject/writeObject functions to break down without proper version difference handling?

Answer (score 2):

If you define `serialVersionUID`, removing or adding a primitive member doesn't break it (missing primitives get their default values). More info: [Java Serialization Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/version.html#6678).

Comment: I actually didn't know this, but it makes sense given that the serialisation bytes generated contains the names of the fields and their values, rather than just the values.

Comment: Yep; it also means that rearranging fields is ok, and renaming fields is equivalent to remove+add. This works as long as serialVersionUID is kept unchanged.

Comment: For example: changing the declared type of a primitive field while keeping the name. See the spec for detials.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile it will break with
java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible Exception
if we don't define  serialVersionUID (which should be static and final)

Comment: @JoonasPulakka, regarding your comment, a renamed field is equivalent to a remove+add and it might "work" but that does not mean that it works in the intended fashion. A rename from the point of view of the programmer should get the earlier serialized value but since it is equivalent to the "add" part of a "remove+add" it will get the default. Not what the programmer intended.