# Deserialize objects, whose class serialVersionUID has changed in Java

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

There is a class `User` that implements `Serializable`, but didn't have a `serialVersionUID` defined in first version.
In the next version I have provided a `final serialVersionUID`.

Now the problem is whenever I try to deserialize the `User` objects that were stored earlier, I get the error:

> static final long serialVersionUID =4061053075992556495L; but expected
>   com.example.android.User: static final long serialVersionUID
>   =-1079331593441085712L;

I am using `FileInputStream` to read the data.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
User object = (User) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Is there any way to deserialize the old objects to this `serialVersionUID`?

Comment: So change the value to the expected value printed in the error message.

Comment: Reworked my answer again. Please let me know if it is in any way helpful.

Answer (score 4):

That is the thing with java serialization: when you messed up like this,  you are *often* broken for good.

But maybe it is as simple as EJP suggests (and is right most often). Then you simply change your **current** class to have that serial uid that the message tells you to use.

**If** the chances you made to your class version after creating those those files are *[compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053359/what-changes-can-make-serialized-class-versions-incompatible)*, then you might be able to solve your problem that way.

If that doesn't work out: turn back your class definition to the old setup. Deserialize those files - and serialize them into another more robust format, for example JSON. Then you can go forward and re-use the JSON content with newer versions of your class that come with changes to the class structure.

Or accept that you lost those files. That is one of the consequences of using concepts without fully understanding them. Painful but sometimes almost inevitable.

Finally: there is one other option. The Java serialization format follows a standard procedure. So it is possible to write a parser for this binary representation of your objects (it would not surprise me if you can find existing tooling doing that for you).

Meaning: if the content of those files is really important to you, you might be able to access the information within the files. You aren't able to deserialize them the "normal" way, but the information is still there and might be accessible, given some effort.

Comment: I will surely work with deserialization using json. I'll accept the answer once I test it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Comment: Do you think this can be possible by somehow tweaking the readObject() method in the serializable class? Can we ignore the serial version uid if we write our own readObject() method?

Comment: *Tweaking* the serialization read/write is close to impossible. Been there, wasted a lot of time; and gave up on it. When you want to use the default ObjectInput/OutputStreams, then you really have to play according to the rules of that thing. I take your comments as: just *adding* that other serial uuid did not help? Do you at least know what kind of chances you made to your class? In any case; for me it is game over for today; if you still have questions, drop me a comment tomorrow.